# click event in Telerik RadGrid HeaderContextMenu columns items?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

In headercontextmenu columns items a checkbox is used to check uncheck columns but i need click command on whole menuItem not just checkbox. There is no click event at server side not even at client side.

At Client side I found this:
grid._getHeaderContextMenu().get_itemData()["3"].items[0]

but it has only three attributes
1.Postback
2.Value
3.Templated

but I need click event.

for reference see this link...
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/headercontextfiltermenu/defaultcs.aspx

right click on header see columns menu items

Comment: are you looking to add those same menus? or your own custom menus?

Comment: I just need click event on same existing menus...